# Retrieve Application Version in ASP Net Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am finishing off building an mvc web application using .net core 2.0 with vs2017 on Win10.In writing an 'About' page I looked to put in the current project version number (at present still set at 1.0.0). I would have thought that pretty straightforward!

The only reference I could find suggested:

```
AppVersion = typeof(RuntimeEnvironment).GetTypeInfo ().Assembly
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute> ().Version;
```

However, this returns, in my case, '4.6.25814.01' - not what is required.

Can anyone suggest how to retrieve the version in code, please?

I assume that I want the 'Package Version' but admit I am not clear on the distinction between/how one would use 'Package Version', 'Assembly Version' and 'Assembly File Version'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you call `typeof(RuntimeEnvironment).Assembly`, you're querying the containing assembly of that type. In this case this would be `System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll` or `Microsoft.Dotnet.PlatformAbstractions.dll`, depending on the namespace you've  imported.

To get the information of your own assembly, you could simply replace `RuntimeEnvironment` with one of your own types, for example

```
var appVersion = typeof(Program).Assembly
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

or even

```
var appVersion = typeof(HomeController).Assembly
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

This would return "6.6.7.0" if the Package version if your project is set as follows:

[image]

You were close!

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/viewing-type-information) you can find more information on reflection for .NET in general, but it should work fine for .NET Core.

Comment: Many thanks, Sigge. That did the job perfectly. Is there any documentation as to the custom attributes available for a project/assembly? For instance, to access other entries in the Project Properties|Package page which may also be useful on an 'About' page?

Comment: Sure! Take a look at the classes in `System.Reflection` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netcore-2.0 and try tinkering with classes such as  `AssemblyCompanyAttribute`, `AssemblyCopyrightAttribute` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tried on version 2.0

```
using System.Reflection;

var appVersion = string.Empty;
var customAttribute = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).SingleOrDefault(o => o.GetType() == typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute));
if (null != customAttribute)
{
    if (customAttribute is AssemblyFileVersionAttribute)
    {
        var fileVersionAttribute = customAttribute as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;
        appVersion = fileVersionAttribute.Version;
    }
}
```

AssemblyFileVersionAttribute type is in System.Reflection namespace.